# Open all E-commerce apps using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to do something like this, I write some product name (eg. Laptop mouse) in my app's edittext and then i click search button and all e-commerce apps which is installed in user's mobile should be shown as an option (Just like share intent). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: With `Intent` there is no way . All actions works on `<intent-filter>`. You can make your own list of packages of Ecommerce apps and filter them with Intent chooser .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think all e commerce apps have similar intent filters. Most apps will include the intent filter `ACTION_VIEW` on their main page but this is also used by many other apps. You can use categories but there's no set standard among e commerce apps.

You'll need to create a custom picker for all the e commerce apps you want to support and add each app independently.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for quick response buddy! you provided me a way!

Comment: @darshanbhatt thanks! Accept this as the answer if this solved your problem